# Docking solution for ultrabooks

Tags: external-display, docking-station, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse, ultrabook

I am seeking to interface with my Samsung Series 9 ultrabook through a larger screen and separate mouse/keyboard, ideally in a manner similar to how Lenovos are commonly docked in corporate environments.

I'm aware that commercially available docking stations are unavailable for most ultrabooks, but **is it possible to emulate a "docking station" for an ultrabook, or at least recreate similar functionality? Is a wireless solution possible?**

My plan had been to use an HDMI adapter to connect the UltraBook to a 24" monitor, and use a wireless mouse and keyboard for input, with the UltraBook itself stashed out of view.

Comment: Check out "widi" (wireless display), im not sure if your ultrabook supports it...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiDi

Comment: Seems like the Title and your question are very different things...  If you want to attract people to your actual question - I'd suggest fixing it.

Comment: My apologies nerdwaller- I should have been more clear

Comment: @nerdwaller In light of some edits for clarity's sake, would it be possible to reclassify this question as other than not constructive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as a wireless display is concerned, your ultrabook should support this feature. A common solution would be something like [Intel WiDi](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-wireless-display.html).
Alternatively, you can search for wireless adapters on any online hardware store like [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=wireless%20display%20adapters&Submit=ENE) and get acquainted with the features.

Wireless mouse and keyboard are easily available today. They come with a tiny USB dongle which is just plug and play. You plug in the adapter, switch on your mouse/keyboard and you are good to go.

Comment: Google is your friend, you only need to use the appropriate keywords :)